# ASP.Net: Do I include the <script> tags inside the <head> tags, or just leave the whole thing alone?

Tags: html, asp.net

I don't know/use ASP.NET and the files are all .ascx. I don't want to break anything.

I don't know what sort of script is in the script tags because ASP.NET is still so foreign to me; it doesn't have a 'type=' but says 'runat="server"'.

I have been tasked with changing the HTML in the .ascx pages. We have historically use SharePoint Designer (still) to edit the content, which has led to several styles being mixed and the pages being in different fonts and sizes and it's all a big mess.

I just want to know if I should put  in , before , or after .

Head/Style:

```
<head>
<style>
p {
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Script tags:

```
<script runat = "server">
   public sting DoTheThing()
   {
     ...
   }
</script>
```

Edit to add:
I am not sure whether the head also had to run server-side like
`<head runat = "server" >` and then what that might do to my  tag.

Comment: It looks like that script runs server-side C# code, so it's different from a normal client-side <script> tag (e.g. JavaScript). You can put the style block anywhere in the <head> section, but not inside the <script> block.

Comment: @James OK, thank you. It's good to know that I'm right to be "suspicious" of <script> tags in ASP.Net (in that they're different). That's part of why I didn't know whether putting it in the head would be a problem.

I wasn't sure whether the head also had to run server-side like
`<head runat= "">` and then what that might do to my <style> tag.

Comment: The runat="server" basically means that the tag won't appear in the HTML output the same way it appears in the source file. ASP.NET will do some magic with it first, and render some different HTML. If you're just making cosmetic changes then you can ignore it. You won't need to set runat="server" to any new tags you create.

Comment: @James Sorry, I'm not being clear enough.
If I make it `<head runat = "server"><script>...</script><style>...</style><script></head>` will the style still apply to my page if it's running server side? or for it to be effective do I need the style tags to run client side? Is it better to have `<head><script runat = "server"></script><style></style>`?

Comment: The second one seems right. Try it out and see.